# gitlab-ci and maven-metadata

Tags: maven, gitlab-ci, spring-cloud-contract

I'm a newbie on gitlab-ci and get a trouble with maven. I'm using the library spring-cloud-contract to test my API. In the code I have this:

```
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(ids = {"my.groupid:artifactid:+:stubs"}, stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.LOCAL)
```

I use the '+' to get the latest version of the stub. When the tests is executed, the library is looking for maven metadata to get the last version.

In my .gitlab-ci.yml, I configured maven with `-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository`

Finally, I have the following error during the execution of the test:

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
> refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name
> 'ClientContractTest$ServerConfiguration':
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'stubFinder'; nested
> exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'batchStubRunner' defined in class path
> resource
> [org/springframework/cloud/contract/stubrunner/spring/StubRunnerConfiguration.class]:
> Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate
> [org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.BatchStubRunner]:
> Factory method 'batchStubRunner' threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: For groupId [my.groupid]
> artifactId [artifactid] and classifier [stubs] **the version was
> not resolved!**
>
> **The following exceptions took place
> [org.eclipse.aether.transfer.MetadataNotFoundException: Could not find
> metadata my.groupid:artifactid/maven-metadata.xml in local
> (/builds/jeromevdl/project/myproject/.m2/repository)]**

Answer (score 2):

It works when using `-Dmaven.repo.local=/root/.m2/repository` (full) instead of `-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository` (relative)

Comment: It seems that the path needs to be absolute. That's also what the Maven doc says: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html.